# how to parse this json data in php (replace " with &quot;)

Tags: php, thinkphp

I get a json data from Android App which looks like

`{&quot;NickName&quot;:&quot;Tom&quot;}`

how to get NickName data with php?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php ?

Comment: get null with htmlspecialchars_decode @Viliam Aboši

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `html_entity_decode` to make json data and  `json_decode` to get name

Check in fiddle : https://eval.in/780633

```
  <?php
   $str = "{&quot;NickName&quot;:&quot;Tom&quot;}";
   echo $text = html_entity_decode($str);
   echo "\n";
   echo json_decode("$text")->NickName;
  ?>
```